# How to make a dynamic menu with a sub-menu ( Arduino mega or Arduino Uno)

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, programming, lcd, rfid

I have an arduino mega with a LCD shield (from keyestudio KS2056). I am trying to create a menu with a submenu that would have addable and removable strings based on inputs from a RFID scanner(addable) and buttons(to remove selected strings). I am not so sure how I could possibly do this. Any assistance would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I will skip the RFID part, that is unrelated to the menu.

What you can do is creating two variables:

```
int menuLevel1 = 0;
int menuLevel2 = 0;
```

Assuming you have 2 levels, if you have more levels consider an array.

Now you can print the screen based on the values of these two variables (use a `switch` statement for menuLevel1 which calls new functions, each with their own `switch` statement for menuLevel2.

Note there are more solutions, but this is a rather simple solution.

The RFID scanner just changes the values, so going to a different menu screen.

A slightly different solution is to not use numbers, but an enumeration (or one for the main level, and x for the second level etc). This can add up, so you can also use a single enum value (with one entry per possible menu page).

The last example looks like:

```
enum EMenuPage
{
   StartPage,
   MainMenu,
   FirstMenu,
   DisplayX,
   SetY,
   …
}

enum EMenuPage _menuPage;
```

Displaying like:

```
switch (_menuPage)
{
case StartPage:
   // Fill LCD with start page
   break;

case …
```

And when an RFID messages comes in:

```
if (RFID... == Back)
{
  _menuPage = MainMenu;
}
else …
```

Answer (score 0):

[State machines][1]. it's the general form of the solution provided by michael above. it's a big help on situations when the application have to answer to, or act on many states (e.g. a menu). the good part is you can `draw them on a piece of paper` , draw a graph, manage input/output and write a general routine to act in various states. the state names themsevles can be represented by an integer variable and represented better by enumeration. after that, there should be a routine to act based on the current state, and the input from current state to go to another state. in it's easiest form, it's just a `if-else` block.
depsite the idea is the same as the bare variable solution provided in the other answers, ignoring state machine related techniques (e.g. just drawing state graphs down on a piece of paper) makes a big application unmanageable.